# Native Ubuntu (libnotify) notifications from Google+ (plus) What's happening?

Tags: 12.10, google-plus

[image: The notification is from the "Explore" tab on G+]After Ubuntu 12.10 fresh install I'm sometimes seeing native Ubuntu notifications from the Google+ "Explore tab". This happens (as far as I know) only when I'm logged onto the G+ website. It seems they appear in the order just like they are posted in G+. (From top down)
I don't know how to reproduce it. I have only noticed it 3-4 times. When they come they come one after another until "all" are shown...
How to control it? (I would love to have that kind of notification for posts for me.)

Answer (score 0):

There are new »Webapps« in Ubuntu 12.10. Maybe you installed one of them? They can now send notifications and stuff directly to your desktop: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/ubuntu-unveil-new-web-apps-feature-for-12-10

Or it's just a native notification (HTML 5 allows notifications, and I have a chrome extensions that makes them native).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I do have the WebApp for G+ installed, the problem is that notifications ONLY shows post from the explore tab, never seen a real "notification" for ME personally. In addition I have just seen it a couple of times...it's not consistent.. Using Firefox by the way, don't have any other extensions installed for Firefox that would allow HTML5 notifications....